# What is the etymology of kanji 関?

Tags: kanji, etymology

I didn't find an explanation or clear etymology for the kanji 関.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kanji etymologies are often more an aspect of Chinese than Japanese.  Wiktionary tends to be a good source for Chinese character origins and some sense development.

- [Entry for 関](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%96%A2#Glyph_origin)
- [Entry for older *kyūjitai* 關](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%97%9C#Glyph_origin)

As we see there, this was originally composed as semantic (meaning) element 門 ("gate, door") + phonetic (sound) element  (probably something like //*kroːn// in Old Chinese), referring to a door being closed or locked.